# Does a 5,5x2,1 DC plug fit into 5,7x2,1 jack?

Tags: power-supply, dc, connector

Is this going to be a reliable contact long term at max power ~50W and will the fit be somewhat snug?

Comment: So difficult to find the right parts...

Comment: @ThomasWeller: there is only an 0.2 mm difference, not 2.0 mm.  The 5.5 mm plug will be a bit loose in a 5.7 mm jack, but will probably work.

Comment: Loose connector and high wattage? For a low-wattage standard connector? That's just asking for trouble.

Comment: @Sadikov What does the current rating for the connector say?

Comment: The part on a cable is a "plug". The part on the product is a "jack".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 5.5 mm or 5.7 mm is the outside diameter of the plug, or of the plug that the socket is intended to accept.

A 5.5 mm plug will fit easily in a 5.7 mm socket, but will be a bit loose.  It will probably make contact with the socket, but the right size plug would be preferable.